# Embedding a <link> tag as plain text within <code> or <pre>

Tags: html

How can I get `<link href="css/file.css"/>` to show as plain text within a `<code>` or `<pre>` tag?

For example: `<code><link href="css/file.css"/></code>`

When I do it as shown in my example, the browser actually includes the CSS file within the page!

Comment: See [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1091945/1497596).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `<` with `&lt;` and `>` with `&gt;`.